# How to pass single String value from Python sub-process code to R Code

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, flask, subprocess

I am trying to run a R code from the Python using Subprocess library.
I need to run one .R file from the python and have pass one single String value(args = ["INV28338"]).
I am new in R and so not able to figure out exact data type conversion code in both R and Python.

Please someone help me, how to pass single string/scalar value from Python to R Function/Model ?
Later I will give the shape of 'Flask REST API' for this code.

Thank you so much in advance

## Python code:-

```
import subprocess
command = 'Rscript'
path2script = 'classification_model_code.R'
args = ["INV28338"]
cmd = [command, path2script] + args
x = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)
print('The Output is:', x)
```

## R code:-

```
myArgs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
nums = as.numeric(myArgs)
invoice_in_scope<-nums
#Followed by more code
```

Comment: Hi Gautam, welcome to SO. The issue is with your python, not R. I have posted below the way to run the shell R. As for your Flask REST API, if you have an issue, it's better to post another question :) Avoid asking multiple questions, inside a single post.

Answer (score 0):

my script, test2.R

```
myArgs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
nums = as.character(myArgs)
print(nums)
```

you need to have `args` as part of the list, so append it to `cmd` and it works ok:

```
import subprocess 
command = 'Rscript' 
path2script = './test2.R' 
args = "INV28338" 
cmd = [command, path2script]
cmd.append(args)
x = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True) 
print('The Output is:', x)
```

Comment: Yes, but still args = "INV28338" is not working in this above function, R code is not able to save this value in 'nums' variable. whereas args = "9" is working fine.

what change I need to make when I will pass ="INV28338"

Comment: hey, "INV28338" is not numeric. You need it as character. nums = as.character(myArgs). See my edited answer